# Is there an JPQL null safe expression

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

In the following JPQL query:

`SELECT NEW com.java2s.common.EmployeeDetails(e.name, e.salary, e.department.name) FROM Employee e`

how can I pass `null` to constructor (as 3rd argument) if `e.department` is `null`?

I guess `e.department.name` will result in an exception if `e.department` is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess e.department.name will result in an exception if e.department is null?

No. `e.department.name` does an implicit *inner* join between the Employee and the Departement tables. So if an employee doesn't have any department, then the employee won't even be returned by the query.

If you want employees without a department to be selected, you need a *left* join:

```
select new com.java2s.common.EmployeeDetails(e.name, e.salary, d.name)  
from Employee e
left join e.department d
```

The above query would return the name and the salary of the employee, and null as the name of the department if the employee doesn't have a department.

Note: experimenting is a really good way of transforming guesses into facts. Why don't you try that query instead of guessing what it will do?

Comment: Currently, I'm experimenting with asking questions on SO :) I'm not so versed with that :)

Comment: I did experiment some more :) If I want `e.department.id` instead of `e.department.name`, then the query is localized to the current table since there is all information needed.
There will be no joins in that case.